# Why am I getting com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractResource$MissingResourceException: No resource found for key '<key>'?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I'm having here this simple `MenuViewMessage`:

```java
package com.mz.client.landing.resource.lang;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages;

public interface MenuViewMessages extends Messages {

    public static final MenuViewMessages LANG = GWT.create(MenuViewMessages.class);

    String registerBusiness();
}
```

As well as these **.properties** files in the *same* package `com.mz.client.landing.resource.lang`:

**menuviewmessages.properties**

```
registerBusiness=Register Business
```

**menuviewmessages_en.properties**

```
registerBusiness=Register Business
```

**menuviewmessages_de.properties**

```
registerBusiness=Gewerbe anmelden
```

However, if I compile it I'm getting

```
[INFO]       Compiling module com.mz.client.ClientEntryPoint
[INFO]          Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.mz.client.landing.resource.lang.MenuViewMessages'
[INFO]             Rebinding com.mz.client.landing.resource.lang.MenuViewMessages
[INFO]                Invoking generator com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator
[INFO]                   Processing interface com.mz.client.landing.resource.lang.MenuViewMessages
[INFO]                      Generating method body for registerbusiness()
[INFO]                         [ERROR] No resource found for key 'registerbusiness'
[INFO] com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractResource$MissingResourceException: No resource found for key 'registerbusiness'
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the key annotation to your message:

```
@Key("registerBusiness")
String registerBusiness();
```

Also, if you name you class MenuViewMessages you should follow the same format with your properties: MenuViewMessages.properties

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you didn't specify a default messages file (e.g MenuViewMessages.properties) plus you custom files for the different languages supported.

Or you can simply get rid of the default messages file ( e.g MenuViewMessages.properties) and work with annotations such as `@DefaultMessage`

Here is an example :

```
package com.mz.client.landing.resource.lang;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages;

public interface MenuViewMessages extends Messages {

       public static final MenuViewMessages LANG = GWT.create(MenuViewMessages.class);

       @DefaultMessage("please register your business")
       String registerBusiness();
}
```